# Can we tune Quick Access in the Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10-quick-access

I find the Quick Access feature in Windows Explorer (in particular under Windows 10) pretty useful. But I am missing some functionality:

- a list of Recent folders instead of Frequent,
- a list of Frequent files instead of Recent,
- the possibility to increase the length of these list.

Are these options possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer how to add Recent folders to Quick Access:

- Open Explorer
- Copy/Paste this into the address bar and press Enter:
  `shell:::{22877a6d-37a1-461a-91b0-dbda5aaebc99}`
- Right-click "Quick Access" on the far-left and select
  "Pin current folder to Quick Access"
- Drag the new entry to the position you prefer.

Comment: Very interesting (anyway, I would prefer that the content of this folder be visible at all times). How did you find this info ?

Comment: I searched for the string (not very easy to remember something like that).

Comment: Er, which string ?

Comment: `22877a6d-37a1-461a-91b0-dbda5aaebc99`. It's one of many, but unfortunately there is none for Frequent files (I looked).

Comment: Then my question still holds: how did you find this info ? (AFAIK, it is not popular wisdom that dbda5aaebc99 refers to the frequent folders ;-) )

Comment: Another bad news is that the pinning does not persist in the "open file" dialog boxes of applications, even though Quick Access is there as well.

Comment: For the list, see [Windows: known folders](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/dirs/_known-folders). Regarding the pinning: Unfortunately, Windows has many inconsistencies.

Comment: WOW, I learnt a lot ! Thanks.